# How to not use pylint-django in non Django file?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm new to the Django. I am currently use VS code as my code editor.

In order to work on the Django project, in the user settings of the VS code, I include the following code to use pylint_django as the default linter.

```
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django", "--errors-only"
    ],
```

However, in another python file, which is just a regular python file, I got an error, saying "Django is not available on the PYTHONPATHpylint(django-not-available)"

If I comment the above code in the user setting, the error goes away. I think the problem is pylint-django is used as default linter, even for non-Django python file.

My question is I didn't find the solution to solve this problem. Could you please help me on this? Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved when I uninstall the globally installed pylint_django.